# PHP No Reload Submit Value into MySQL Database (no return)

Tags: php, mysql

So what I am doing is trying to create a 'favorite' system. I want the user to click a button and the code on the page will submit a value into a MySQL Database. Does this need to the page need to reload if the only thing I am doing is submit and value. I am not pulling any information from the database on the button's click. Thank you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great way to avoid the complexities of Ajax and cross-browser compatibility is to use Jquery!

In your non-reloading page, you can put this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script text="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('#button_id').click(function() { //in place of "button_id" you need to put your button's id
    submitInformation("some information you want to send");
});
});
function submitInformation(data1)
{
$.post(
    "handle.php", //this is the name and location of your php page
    {
        "input_var_one":data1,
    }
);
}
</script>
```

and in your handler php page (in this case called "handle.php")

```
<?php
$inData1 = $_POST['input_var_one'];


//after your mysql_connect and mysql_select_db
$query = "INSERT INTO `yourtablename` VALUES ('var1 whatever you want', '$inData1')";
mysql_query($query);

?>
```

Jquery handles the Ajax request for you!

Comment: In general, I believe teaching people to use jquery is not such a good idea, just that for many using jquery equals "not needing to learn javascript", and this gets us to many who knows as much about what might be the real problem (in case of an anomaly) as a snail about its shell.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to respond quicker Thanks so much! Very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use AJAX, the information must be sent to the server in order to get to a mysql database table and processed by php and that surely requires page reload.

you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var xhr = XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

function onthatbuttonclick(something)
{
    window.xhr.open('GET', "somephp.php?click="+something, false);
    window.xhr.send(null);
    alert(window.xhr.responseText);
}

var somevar = "user 01";
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="onthatbuttonclick(somevar);" />
```

and in php:

```
<?php
    // some query required code

    // and yes... i does require some safety measures:
    $val = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['click']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tabel` (`click`) VALUES ('".$val."')");
    echo 'you cliked a button.';
?>
```

you should now see an alert box with the text: "you clicked a button.".

Comment: yikes! i know this is the bare essentials, but with php you always need to sanitize your database inputs.

Comment: Ajax will probably serve you best in this instance, but it isn't the only way to do this without a page load. For small project it's often easier to do submissions to hidden iframes within the page. Give the iframe a name, and set the form to submit to that frame (<form target='iframe_name'...) This can be easier to trouble-shoot and requires a lot less code.... In any case, ajax is an essential skill, but I wanted to clarify this point.

Comment: @BenD probably an iframe would do the job, but nowadays it became a hell to work with, by my knowledge there are 4 main techniques to mimic ajax, but all implies some consequences. To structure the code, even if it is a small project, might be hell.

Comment: To be fair, the iframe submission method predates ajax. I agree that ajax is generally the way to go (you can do a lot more, and more of the code will be recyclable, but I've found that debugging is much faster using iframes. The major drawback is that it is much more difficult to handle errors, but many (most?) projects don't seem to do a decent job with that even when they have the tools available. In any case, I just wanted to highlight that it's not entirely true that without ajax it "requires page reload"... your answer is still solid :)